# why can I not see the unallocated space in gparted

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

so I have triple booted windows, kali, and ubuntu. I am trying to resize ubuntu /home directory which sits on the HDD. So I created a new unallocated space in windows of 200gb size, and I want to add it to ubuntu

[image]

however the problem is I do not see it in gparted as free space or as anything. I simply do not see it. As you can see in the picture, /dev/sdb5 is the one I want to grow, but I cannot see 200gb free space
[image]

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Disk 1 is **Dynamic** which is Proprietary to Microsoft.  In order to properly share the disk with other non-MS operating systems the disk must be converted to **Basic** as can be seen with Disk 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does conversion from dynamic to basic cause data losses. I do not know how it became dynamic in the first place